# create an array removing duplicate names and in alphabetical order

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an NSMutableArray containing dictionaries of entries. Each entry has several keys of which one is "Title" which contains a name string.

There are many duplicates in the data model because some entries are related to different sections. For example, "Influenza" might be found under "Fever" or "Aches and Pain". So, now I  have a key-value pair with two entries called "Influenza" as a title.

When implementing search in a TableViewController, if I type in "Influenza", I get duplicates. In order to remove them, I tried the following:

```
self.searchEntries = [[NSSet setWithArray:entries]allObjects];
[searchEntries sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareName:)];
```

However, this doesn't seem to do anything useful. I still get duplicates and the list isn't in alphabetical order.

Can anyone help me with this seemingly simple matter?

Answer (score 1):

Are your duplicates really duplicates? Or are there any special characters/caps?

For sorting, you'll have to do

```
searchEntries = [searchEntries sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareName:)];
```

as `- sortedArrayusingSelector:` will return an NSArray.

**Update:**
As `entries` contains elements of type `NSDictionary`, you can get the unique & sorted array as follows:

```
searchEntries = [entries valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.title"];
searchEntries = [searchEntries sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Note that `searchEntries` now only contains the title values (which might be ok if you just want to display them in a tableView).

Comment: Thanks tilo. The sorting method works wonderfully. As for the duplicates, I just want to compare strings, like "Influenza".

Comment: Your `entries` contains "Influenza",..."Influenza",..? If so, your NSSet should contain only one "Influenza". Can you post an example?

Comment: That's the strange thing... the NSSet returns with multiple "Influenza"s for some reason. I'm probably doing something wrong elsewhere but can't seem to find an error.

Comment: What does `entries` contain? Elements of class `NSString`, `NSDictionary`, custom objects?

Comment: `entries` is a NSMutableArray which contains dictionaries with six different `NSString` and one `int`. The name of each entry is under the "Title" key with the value which is the name, which in this case is "Influenza". So, I'm hoping to get an `NSMutableArray` with dictionaries where the "Title" isn't duplicated. Hope this is clear...

Comment: hmmm... this works (it displays in the tableView without duplicates) but I would need the whole dictionary of key/value pairs since I would need to use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the tableView in order to call up a detail view.

Comment: There is a logical error: When there is only one "Influenza", which dictionary should be called? The one with "Fever", "Aches and Pain", or something else?

Comment: I see what you mean... They all lead to the same information but accessed from different places. So, my dictionary with the title "Influenza" and symptom "Fever" and another dictionary with "Influenza" and symptom "Aches and Pains" would be considered 2 different objects by `NSSet`. Is this the correct assumption? If so, then you're right: there is a logical error. I'll have to find another way.

Comment: Of course they are different objects. You could display only one "Influenza" and push a detailView with multiple symptoms. But this is another topic ;-)

Answer (score 1):

i hope this code help to u

```
NSSet *uniqueElements = [NSSet setWithArray:myArray];

// iterate over the unique items
for(id element in uniqueElements) {
  // do something
}
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

First of all the objects in your array all need to respond to the selector you choose.  NSDictionary does not respond to compareName: as far as I'm aware.

Secondly, sortedArray... methods create a whole new array.  NSMutableArray has some [in place sort methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-SW6).

Probably the easiest thing is to use if you have a mutable array `-sortUsingComparator:` e.g.

```
[[self searchEntries] sortUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2)
    {
        return [[obj1 title]  compare: [obj2 title]];
    }];
```

If you have an immutable array

```
sortedArray = [[self searchEntries] sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2)
              {
                  return [[obj1 title]  compare: [obj2 title]];
              }];
```

Comment: Thanks JeremyP, but how would I do this for over 300 entries?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  That sorts the entire array using the given block to compare the elements in the array.